# A quick question squares that is equal to a power of $2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I think I've seen this somewhere else, but I can't remember where.

Does there exist any integer $n$ such that $n^2 = 2^{n}, n>2^8$ ?

If anyone has a link to relevant material, it would be much appreciated if you share.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. By induction you quickly show that $2^n>n^2$ for all $n\ge 5$. Hint for this: $\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}= \left(1+\frac1n\right)^2\le \frac{36}{25}<2$.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the graphs $y = \sqrt{2^x}$ and $y=x$. Not only are there no integer solutions in that range, there aren't any positive real solutions apart from the two trivial ones.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

Notice that we have equality for n=2. Consider too, the two functions $f:=2^x$ and $g:=x^2$; then $f'(x)=(ln2)2^x$, and $g'(x)=2x$. Use the approximation $ln2=0.69$, compare the two derivatives:

Set, $(0.69)2^x:=2x$, so that $(0.69)2^{x-1}=x$ . Then$ f'(x)>g'(x)$ for $x>4$ (maybe double-check that $f''(x)>g''(x)$ for $x>4$.

So , the two functions agree at n=2, then do not agree on n=3, are equal at 4, and then f(x) grows faster than g(x) afterwords, so the two will never meet again--look at the difference between , say, $2^{32}=4294967296$ , and $32^2=1024$
 .